# Obter dados de várias tabelas codeigniter (Array multidimensional)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como obter dados de várias tabelas de uma só vez?

Preciso recuperar os dados do seguinte objeto (devedor).

Existem várias tabelas, onde a tabela principal é a `tbl_devedor`.
Depois disso, vem outras, que são relacionadas a `tbl_devedor`.

Exemplo:

- `tbl_devedor`
- `tbl_email`
- `id_contrato`
- `id_telefone`
- `id_endereco`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o `array`

```
$dados = array(
    'contratos' => [],
    'id' => '',
    'id_operador' => 0,
    'pessoa_fisica' => array(
          'id' => 0,
          'rg' => '',
          'dt_nascimento' => '',
          'profissao' => '',
          'salario' => '',
          'genero' => '',
        ),
    'pessoa_juridica' => array (
         'id' => 0,
         'nome_fantasia' => '',
         'inscricao_estadual' => ''
    ),
    'nome' => '',
    'cpf_cnpj' => '',
    'emails' => [],
    'enderecos' => [],
    'telefones' => [],
    'crud' => null
);

echo json_encode($dados);
```

Lembrando que `contratos`, `pessoa_fisicao`, `pessoa_juridica`, `emails`, `enderecos`, `telefones`, vem de tabelas diferentes, até o momento o que tenho é isso:

Controller

```
$devedor = $this->devedor->obter_por_id($id);
```

Model

```
public function obter_por_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_devedor);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Eu sei fazer o join e obter os dados das outras tabelas, porem não sei como deve ficar a estrutura do `array`.

Comment: Wagner você precisa colocar na sua pergunta o diagrama de banco com essas tabelas.

Comment: Ok!
Feito isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo as *informações* sendo *relacionadas*, eu faria uma classe [Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model) para cada ***tabela*** e depois uma classe [Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model) para gerenciar as outras da seguinte forma:

***Exemplo Minimo:***

<sub>***Observação:*** nesse exemplo simples foi colocado duas dessas tabelas as outras seguem o mesmo `layout` de programação e a ideia proposta.</sub>

> class `Devedor_model`

```
<?php

    class Devedor_model extends CI_Model 
    {

        public function obter_por_id($id)
        {
            $this->db->from('tbl_devedor');
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->row_array();
        }

    }
```

---

> class `Devedoremail_model`

```
<?php

    class Devedoremail_model extends CI_Model 
    {   

        public function obter_por_id_email($id)
        {
            $this->db->from('tbl_devedor_email');
            $this->db->where('devedor_id',$id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }

    }
```

essas duas classes [Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model) seriam utilizadas agora em uma outra classe [Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model) que iria gerenciar e manipular esses dados de uma vez só e vão gerar o `array` esperado:

```
<?php

    class Devedordados_model extends CI_Model 
    {
        private $CI;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            // subindo as classe model coloque todas
            $this->CI->load->model("devedor_model");
            $this->CI->load->model("devedoremail_model");
        }

        public function obter_todos_dados_por_id($id)
        {
            $result = array();
            $result = $this->devedor_model->obter_por_id($id);
            $result['email'] = $this->devedoremail_model->obter_por_id_email($id);
            // insere aqui os outros models 
            //$result['enderecos'] = 
            //$result['telefones'] = 
            return $result;
        }

    }
```

e finalmente no `controller` é chamado a classe que gerencia todos os [Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model), `Devedordados_model`:

```
public function de()
{
    $id = 1;
    $this->load->model('Devedordados_model');

    echo json_encode($this->Devedordados_model->obter_todos_dados_por_id($id),
                     JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

o resultado obtido por esse método do `Controller`:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "nome": "Devedor 1",
    "email": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "email": "d1@d1.com",
            "devedor_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "email": "d2@d1.com",
            "devedor_id": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

e essa seria uma proposta, mediante a sua duvida

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Models](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#models)
- [Auto-loading Models](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model#auto-loading-models)

Comment: Deu certo desta forma, obrigado..

Comment: só uma outra dúvida, nesta parte `public function obter_por_id_email($id)
        {
            $this->db->from('tbl_devedor_email');
            $this->db->where('devedor_id',$id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }` eu consigo alterar um campo individualmente, antes de retorna-lo ao objeto devedor ?

Comment: tentei assim e não funcionou:
`foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)`

Comment: Cara seja bem especifico que talvez não precise percorrer um array talvez um alias já resolva, mas, me diga na totalidade o que precisa fazer @WagnerFilho

Comment: Porque quando eu obtenho por id, `obter_por_id_email`
Eu pego todos os campos e exibo exatamente o que está no banco de dados.

Estes são os campos da tabela `tbl_devedor_email`, `'id', 'email', 'crud', 'devedor_id', 'id_origem_dados', 'observacao', 'preferencial', 'situacao'`

Se porventura, o campo `crud` tiver um resultado igual a `C`, o objeto recupera `crud: C`.
Eu quero alterar este campo para `crud: R`.

Comment: Olha não entendi a sua duvida está confuso CRud C Crud R não entendi mesmo .... @WagnerFilho só fala o que é pra ser feito, só uma coisa, essa é uma nova duvida se porventurar quiser abra uma nova!

Comment: A finalidade da pergunta era recuperar os dados em geral; quanto a isso OK, está funcionando..

Agora, ao recuperar os dados da tabela email, por exemplo, eu quero alterar o resultado de um dos campos, neste caso, o campo `crud`.

Comment: O campo `crud` que faz parte da `tbl_devedor`, você quer mostrar outro valor no resultdo, ou/e também mudar o valor que está gravado na base salvando o novo valor? @WagnerFilho

Comment: Somente mostrar outro valor no resultado.
Pois quando este valor for recuperado pelo json, o sistema irá entender, que o método a ser utilizado é o R.

Comment: Veja este imagem: https://ibb.co/fSHwU5

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64758/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-wagner-filho).

Comment: Pode me ajudar novamente ?
Se o eu acrescentar um novo campo ao objeto `email`. este campo se chamará, `view` e está `view` deve recuperar dados de outra tabela.
Como posso fazer isso?
Seria algo assim: `view: {id: "1", nome: "admin":}`

Comment: Se poderia abrir outra pergunta @WagnerFilho anexando essa como resposta primária?

Comment: Questão aberta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235596/obter-dados-array-multidimensional-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment482290_235596