# Obter dados Array multidimensional (codeigniter)?

Tags: codeigniter

Tive um caso solucionado através da questão [deste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232573/54880) aqui no SO e agora estou com uma outra dúvida, que é a seguinte:

Seguindo o exemplo da questão acima, tenho a seguinte tabela `tbl_devedor_contrato`, com os seguintes campos:

```
`id`
`plano`
`contrato`
`dt_contrato`
`dt_expiracao`
`crud`
`assessoria_id`
`empresa_id`
`importacao_id`
```

No retorno do objeto, eu preciso acrescentar um item a este objeto. Este item será chamado `view`, onde deverá recuperar dados de outra tabela `tbl_devedor_negociacao`.

***O output seria algo assim:***

```
`id = 1`
`plano = 10`
`contrato = 1`
`dt_contrato = 2017-09-08`
`dt_expiracao = 9999-09-08`
`crud = C`
`assessoria_id = 1`
`empresa_id = 1`
`importacao_id = 0`
`view = id = 1
       dt_negociacao = 1`
       atualizar = 1`
       id_finalizacao = 1`
       contrato_id = 1`
       crud = 1`
```

Acontece que este item `view`, não existe na tabela `tbl_devedor_contrato` ?

Então como posso criar este item, já que não existe na tabela e atribuir valores ao mesmo.

***Abaixo tenho o relacionamento que preciso fazer:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Model:***

```
//Obter devedor por ID | Contrato
public function obter_por_id_contrato($id)
{
    $this->db->from('tbl_devedor_contrato');
    $this->db->where('devedor_id',$id);
    $this->db->select("tbl_devedor_contrato.*, IF(tbl_devedor_contrato.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud", FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}`
```

Comment: Você quer inserir um coluna chamada view na table `tbl_devedor_email` e dentro dessa coluna colocar dados de outra tabela, é isso ?

Comment: @LeandroLima, eh isso, porem recuperar da forma que está na outra questão.

Comment: O link pra outra questão está quebrado. Me arrisco a dizer que isso que você quer fazer é uma má prática e que deve ter outra maneira mais fácil de resolver isso. Porem não consigo orientar qual seria essa melhor maneira. Você sabe fazer relacionamento de tabelas (?) Não é isso que você tá procurando ?

Comment: @LeandroLima, Link atualizado. Eu sei fazer relacionamentos de tabelas, mas acredito que não seja este caso.

Comment: veja esta imagem, para voce ter uma ideia. https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/img-png--129

Comment: 1) será que precisa criar esse campo para retornar um dado de outra tabela, 2) como você vai recuperar os dados dessa tabelas de `logs` qual vai ser o parâmetro para tal recuperação? e 3) quais os campos da tabela `logs` vai ser relacionado e recuperados para exibir esse campo `view` que no entendimento primário não precisa ser fisico só virtual (ou seja, não precisa existir, mas, ser montado igual no exemplo da outra resposta). Coloque tudo isso na sua questão e [para editar veja link de criação e edição de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: 1) Não preciso criar este campo. 
2) Se houvesse um campo criado, seria por INNER JOIN. 
3) Realmente este campo não precisa ser físico, somente virtual.

Comment: Eu coloquei a tabela de `email` como exemplo, porem esta `view`, será aplicada na tabela `contrato`, e esta `view` irá exibir o nome da empresa, cujo campo `ID` está presente na tabela contrato. `empresa_id`. Veja este exemplo JSON e verá um exemplo: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/VMf30KK5

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, consegue me ajudar a criar esta `view`? criando isso, eu já consigo me virar com o restante.

Comment: Wagner sim mas faz o seguinte coloque as duas tabelas envolvidas + relação + campos obtidos ai eu promova uma resposta ok

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz uma atualização na questão, pode ver se ajuda ?

Comment: A sua duvida é porque o resultado de contrato é uma lista e ai voce precisa interar nessa lista e anexar os item referente a negociação?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, exatamente. Assim como em negociacoes, preciso integrar as parcelas.. eu preciso obter as negociações do contrato e respectivamente as parcelas das negociações

Comment: Da forma como está, só exibi no resultado, os campos reais da tbl_devedor_contrato. Então antes de criar o objeto completo, eu preciso incluir o item view, para saber quais são as negociações deste contrato e respectivamente as parcelas

Comment: Deu certo ???  Wagner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O trabalho é meio confuso, no primeiro momento, mas, gratificante quando se tem um resultado esperado, precisa utilizar mecanismos otimizados para que essa montagem não fique com baixo desempenho e não acesse demasiadamente o banco de dados, com 3 [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) e funções do PHP ([array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)), pode ter o resultado esperado, vou propor um ***exemplo minimo*** que pode e deve ser refletido na sua pergunta [mediante a primeira resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232573/54880):

***Diagrama da base de dados***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essas tabelas possui relacionamentos de 1 para muitos e precisa ser unidas para gerar um [json](/questions/tagged/json) com todas as informações de um determinado `devedor` (`$devedor_id`).

***Classes***

*Devedor Contrato*

```
<?php

class Devedorcontrato_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function obter_contrato_devedor_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from('tbl_devedor_contrato');
        $this->db->where('devedor_id',$id);
        $this->db->order_by('id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

*Devedor Negociações*

```
<?php

class Devedornegociacao_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function obter_negociacao_devedor_id($id)
    {

        $this->db->from('tbl_devedor_negociacao');
        if (is_array($id))
        {
            $this->db->where_in('contrato_id',$id);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->where('contrato_id',$id);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('contrato_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

*Devedor Parcelas*

```
<?php

class Devedorparcelas_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function obter_parcelas_negociacao_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from('tbl_devedor_parcela');
        if (is_array($id))
        {
            $this->db->where_in('negociacao_id',$id);
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->db->where('negociacao_id',$id);  
        }

        $this->db->order_by('negociacao_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

A classe que será responsável em gerir todas essas informações de uma só vez:

```
<?php

    class Devedordados_model extends CI_Model 
    {
        private $CI;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->CI->load->model("devedor_model");
            $this->CI->load->model("devedoremail_model");
            $this->CI->load->model("devedorcontrato_model");
            $this->CI->load->model("devedornegociacao_model");
            $this->CI->load->model("devedorparcelas_model");
        }

        public function obter_todos_dados_por_id($id)
        {
            $result = array();

            //Contratos
            $result['contratos'] = $this->devedorcontrato_model
                                        ->obter_contrato_devedor_id($id);

            //Negociações
            $id_contratos = array_map(function($item)
            { return $item['id'];}, $result['contratos']);
            $negociacoes = $this->devedornegociacao_model
                                ->obter_negociacao_devedor_id($id_contratos);

            //Parcelas
            $id_parcelas = array_map(function($item)
            { return $item['id']; }, $negociacoes);
            $parcelas = $this->devedorparcelas_model
                             ->obter_parcelas_negociacao_id($id_parcelas);


            for($i = 0; $i < count($negociacoes); $i++)
            {
                $id = $negociacoes[$i]['id'];
                $negociacoes[$i]['parcelas'] = 
                    array_filter($parcelas, function($a) use ($id){
                        return $a['negociacao_id'] == $id;
                    });
            }
            for($i = 0; $i < count($result['contratos']); $i++)
            {
                $id = $result['contratos'][$i]['id'];
                $result['contratos'][$i]['negociacoes'] =
                    array_filter($negociacoes, function($a) use ($id){
                        return $a['contrato_id'] == $id;
                    });

            }           

            return $result;
        }

    }
```

nesse método resumido percebe que me atentei as 3 classes que são relacionadas como já havia dito e precisa ser unidas para a geração do [json](/questions/tagged/json), foi empregada a lógica e utilização da função `array_filter` para construção das relações e por fim chame no `controller`:

```
public function de()
{
    $this->load->model('Devedordados_model');

    echo json_encode($this->Devedordados_model->obter_todos_dados_por_id(1),
                              JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

- [Models](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#models)
- [Auto-loading Models](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model#auto-loading-models)
- [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Virgilio, desculpe o atraso, estava fora.
E..Funcionou, perfeito!!
Obrigado

Comment: Uma dúvida, o pulo do gato para construção do json  está no `for`.
`for($i = 0; $i < count($negociacoes); $i++)` e `for($i = 0; $i < count($result['contratos']); $i++)` ?

Comment: @Wagnerfilho sim, mas o array_filter também. De uma.lida no manual

Comment: utilizando a forma que me passou, tenho 2 negociações cadastradas, mas quando obtenho isso, uma negociação vem com suas parcelas em array, mas a outra vem com suas parcelas como objeto. Está correto isso? Não pode vir tudo como array ?
Veja imagem: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/087/921/full/array.png?1505321555

Comment: @WagnerFilho no exemplo que te passei observe que esta result_array então o exemplo esta certo deve ser algo no seu codigo

Comment: Pode me ajudar com a questão?
 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/obter-dados-como-array-e-n%C3%A3o-como-objeto-codeigniter